# VisualForce Page for Contact

Tags: visualforce

How do I make a VisualForce page visible to a contact? I'm trying to build a simple customized page for contacts, behind a login. I'm not asking about how to write the code on the actual page (or at least I don't think I'm asking about that), but only asking about how to make the page accessible to a contact.

Is this possible, or does Salesforce not allow it so that you have to pay for the Service Cloud?

Comment: Does your page access the Contact Object? If so, whether you can make it accessible to a portal user will depend on which license the portal user has.

Comment: It will access the Contact Object. I'm surprised that a contact would need a user license to view their own information. Thanks for clarifying this point.

Comment: That's the limitation. They can only edit their own community contact information, not their SF contact info. Its a security measure. Unless they're a partner or User in your org, would you really want them directly editing the info you have on them in your database??

Comment: I definitely see the security point. I would want contacts be able to update their communications preferences, and be able to view custom content based on their data. 

Would it be possible if it was read-only?

Comment: Again, which community portal license do you have? Is this a chatter free license?

Comment: Sorry, @crmprogdev, I'm a front-end web dev who is super new to Salesforce. Thanks for your patience. We have Chatter Free licenses, but nowhere near enough for the number of contacts.

Comment: Am I completely off-base here? Should this be a force.com site?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14908/discussion-between-crmprogdev-and-natejones).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to setup a [Customer Portal](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customer_portal_setting_up.htm&language=en_US).

Comment: I absolutely do, but we're a new organization, so they're sadly not available to us. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Communities, then?

Comment: I think that may be the only option, Ray. I was hoping to save a bit of money since so many of the Communities features aren't really what I need. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this instruction so you can easily add an VF page to your Contact Object.

Go to the:

```
Setup > Customize > Contacts > Page Layouts
```

Then Choose your page layout (Contact Layout) and click on the "Edit" link at the top left side. Under "Save" button select the "Visualforce Pages" - it displayed you VF page.

Drag the VF as you specified section and then click the save button.
Go to the Contacts on the Tab. Click one contact now your VF page should be displayed.